# Linq: Method that returns first instance with given type

Tags: c#, linq

I often find myself writing code like this:

```
collection.First(s => s is MyType) as MyType;
```

Is there a more specific Linq method, that returns the first element of a certain type?

like this:

```
collection.FirstOfType<MyType>();
```

I also looked in Jon Skeets [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) project, but no luck

Comment: `FirstOfType` doesn't really make much sense to me, as `OfType` is a filter method and `First` is a Range method. Having every filter method combined with ever Range method would result in a massive amount of extension methods, where as `OfType<T>().First()` is almost the same and has clear separation of intent between both.

Comment: @jessehouwing I understand, still I use that functionality so often, that it would make sense (for me at least) to have it. Isn't the same as saying, we dont need `First` with a filter, because you could write `Where(...).First()`?

Comment: So you can still do that as you've shown `.First(o =>  o is Type)`. Almost all Range methods have a default filter convenience **overload**, which is different to me to a cross join between all filters and all range methods. If you use `First` often, someone else will use `Take` and `Last` or `Skip` and you'd end up with `FirstOfType`, `LastOfType`, `TakeOfType`, `SkipOfType` and `FirstCast`, `LastCast` and `TakeCast` and `SkipCast`. It would become an immense mess.

Comment: @jessehouwing you're right, it's a tradeoff between convenience and conciseness of the API. If it had all that methods, I probably wouldn't find anything anymore in intellisense :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to filter collection by specified type:

```
collection.OfType<MyType>().First();
```

Note - if there is possible that no items of `MyType` exist in collection, then use `FirstOrDefault()` to avoid exception.

Internally `OfType` simply uses `is` operator to yield all items which are compatible with given type. Something like this (actually `OfType` returns `OfTypeIterator` which iterates collection):

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    foreach (object obj in source)
    {
        if (!(obj is TResult))
            continue;

        yield return (TResult)obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about `OfType`, but didn't use it for this scenario. Your suggestion is clearly better than what I had. I take it there is no specific method, so thanks!